# Selenium Webdriver startWith() method doesn't work using Java

Tags: java, selenium

Please could someone advise why my `startsWith()` method is red. I am quite new with `Selenium` and `Java`, any help would be much appreciated. 
I am using IntelliJ IDEA community version, `Java` and `Windows 7` platform. 
Below is the code. Very many thanks in advance.

```
public class MyFirstTest {
    @Test
    public void startWebDriver(){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.bbc.co.uk");
        Assert.assertTrue("bbc", driver.getTitle().startsWith("bbc"));
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: getTitle() returns String, that's why it works. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Please be sure to provide related stacktrace for better/quicker answer for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [TestNG assertTrue](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html#assertTrue) overloading.

According to the doc and looking at the test you are trying to accomplish I believe the follwing is the best overloading for this case.

```
public static void assertTrue(boolean condition,
                              java.lang.String message)
```

With that being said, your test is designed to fail as is since BBC's header starts with **BBC**(all caps) and you **are not ignoring case**. To prove that I did the following tests

```
@Test
public void startWebDriver() {
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.bbc.co.uk");

    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.print(title);
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().startsWith("bbc"), "Wrong title found: " + title);

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

> **Output**
>
> BBC - Homepagejava.lang.AssertionError: Wrong title found: BBC - Homepage 
>   Expected :true
>   Actual   :false

And if I chage the `startsWith("bbc")` to `startsWith("BBC")` it passes